# Convert from simple feature geometry to dataframe

Tags: r, r-sf

I wish to plot two shapes next to each other. The shapes are created with the transformR package. This code plots them on top of each  other.

```
library(transformr)
library(ggplot2)


star_1a <- poly_star(n = 5, st = TRUE)
circle_2a <- poly_circle(st = TRUE)

df1 <- data.frame(
  geo = sf::st_sfc(star_1a, circle_2a),
  col = c('steelblue', 'green'),
  id = c(1, 2)
)

ggplot(df1) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry))
```

I could remove the st = TRUE option from each shape to get a dataframe, but let's say I don't want to do that. How do I transform the sfg object into a dataframe with x, y columns so that I can move the circle to the right a bit and then transform them back to sfg objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have a data.frame, and you can perform transformations on the st_sfc objects in it,
using basic [affine transformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf3.html#affine-transformations). For example

```
df1[1,1] = df1[1,1] + c(2,0) 

ggplot(df1) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry))
```

[image]

**Explanatory note:**  `df1[1,1]` selects the first column and row, which is the star.   Adding `c(2,0)` translates it by +2 in the x direction.

**The answer to the question you actually asked:**
If you *really* need the x,y cordinates as columns in a data.frame, you can use

```
df2 = data.frame(st_coordinates(df1[,1]))
```

However, for the use case you described, the first method above will be better.  Not just because it is faster and neater, but because manipulating the sf objects themselves will take care of things like crs and extent.

Comment: Thank-you. Very helpful answer.